# Issue with Google Authenticator QR code URI in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, qr-code, angular5, google-authenticator

I am trying to generate QR code using the NPM module https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-qrcode for the Google Authenticator App with the use of uri which is something like this

```
otpauth://totp/App%3Fsecret=XX47YM3N7JC6EN5B6DHRDNYW2AO74JYK
```

And i am assigning the same with following markup

Variable QRUrl is having the complete uri as mentioned but the qr code generated after rendering is having only upto 30 characters of the value

```
<qr-code _ngcontent-c5="" canvas="true" ng-reflect-size="150" ng-reflect-value="otpauth://totp/App%3Fsecret=XX" ng-reflect-canvas="true"><canvas height="150" width="150"></canvas></qr-code>
```

I have tried looking into the code of the module for any string limit while binding the data to the directive but couldn't find anything wrong which may be doing this. Just wondering if this is something to do with angular version.

Also the same issue occurs in another module that i tried https://github.com/techiediaries/ngx-qrcode

Comment: same issue with https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode module as well

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: don't percent-encode the question mark.

The otpauth URL should look like:

`otpauth://totp/AppName?secret=...`

And not:

`otpauth://totp/AppName%3Fsecret=...`

This should then be a correct input for the qrcode package to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode) mentioned in the comments, but my answer applies to any QR Code lib.

QR Codes have a limited 'volume' to store data, and the available space is narrowed by the actual size of your canvas, the correction level and used QR Code version [[Ref](http://blog.qr4.nl/page/QR-Code-Data-Capacity.aspx)]

The angularx-qrcode lib comes with sensible defaults (size of 256 x 256px, error correction level 'm') to store your data. A size of 150 x 150px can only hold ~1/3 of the libs default.

To get more storage space, you may increase the possible amount of data stored in your QR code with these two options:

1. Increase the canvas-size to 256px and resize your canvas with CSS to 150px
2. lower the correction level

Both options are fine in a digital environment where we rarely encounter issues with loss or dirt.

Sample (for angularx-qrcode):

```
<qrcode [qrdata]="myAngularxQrCode" [size]="256" [level]="'L'"></qrcode>
```